# why graph api explore facebook id and in my android studio generate id are different?

Tags: android-studio, facebook-graph-api, logcat, graph-api-explorer

why  graph API explorer and android studio showing different id?
However my query in both the platform are the same.

Here is my query and id in graph API Explorer:

[image: graph API explorer id]

While here is my id in android studio log cat:

[image: generating id from android studio]

Comment: Hey http://stackoverflow.com/users/4390212/dimasan you edit my post i appreciate but help me to solve that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you did not select your own App in the API Explorer. By default, the "API Explorer" App is selected, so you get a different App Scoped ID because it´s a different App.